# How to use apache camel enrich with JDBC

Tags: apache-camel

Apache Camel 2.12.1

I have a route setup like this:

```
 public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start")
                        .process(new AuthorizationHeaderProcessor(configureCreds()))
                        .to(httpSourceEndpoint)

                        .process(new GenerateSQLFromMessageProcessor))
                        .enrich("jdbc:dataSource", new DBAggregator())
                        //...do things with result...
```

1) HttpSourceEndPoint is a get request from some url.

2) I then want to use the result of this to generate the SQL as per GenerateSQLFromMessageProcessor, which is provided as input to the JDBC route.

My problem is, within the DBAggregator, the parameters that come through are:

```
oldExchange = the raw SQL string that was sent to the JDBC call
newExchange = the result set from the DB query
```

ie there is no sign of the original message that came from the http source endpoint, which is how I would have expected aggregation to work. How am I supposed to combine the 2 streams? Was it the GenerateSQLFromMessageProcessor call that consumed the original message? If so, should you specify the SQL in a bean for an enrich?

**EDIT**

So setting in the header like this:

```
public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("direct:start")
                    .process(new AuthorizationHeaderProcessor(configureCreds()))
                    .to(httpSourceEndpoint)

                    .setHeader(new BeanExpression(MySQLBean.class, "methodToGenerateSQL")
                    .enrich("jdbc:dataSource", new DBAggregator())
                    //...do things with result...
```

results in my aggregator looking like this:

```
public class DBAggregator implements AggregationStrategy {

@Override
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {

Here I have:
    oldExchange = the resulting SQL string that methodToGenerateSQL generated
    newExchange = the result set from the SQL query
```

**The problem is I do not have access to the original message that came from httpSourceEndpoint**.

As this is an aggregator I would have expected oldExchange to be the incoming message, not just an SQL string.
After all, it is an aggregator, and yet I have effectively lost the incoming message - this is not "enriching"!

Thanks,
Mr Tea

Comment: Put the SQL Query String in the header nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Results in the same problem - the original message is then not available in the aggregator. You just get the generated SQL string and the results of the query, NOT the incoming message.

Comment: Place the incoming message into the header then. You say you use a aggregator? Where you code is too incomplete to understand what you are doing.

Comment: I've added some more...